# Google Location Services never updates

Tags: java, android, google-api

I have tried to figure this out for the past 48 hours, but I must be an idiot. I followed the Google documentation to try and make this weather app location aware. The problem is I don't how to make onLocationChanged() run or even know when it is supposed to run. If it doesn't run I send a request to grab data from latitude 0 and longitude 0. I have enabled all the correct permissions. Please help me...

```
package com.brennanglynn.brennanweather.ui;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.brennanglynn.brennanweather.R;
import com.brennanglynn.brennanweather.weather.Current;
import com.brennanglynn.brennanweather.weather.Day;
import com.brennanglynn.brennanweather.weather.Forecast;
import com.brennanglynn.brennanweather.weather.Hour;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected final static String REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY = "requesting-location-updates-key";
    protected final static String LOCATION_KEY = "location-key";
    protected final static String LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY = "last-updated-time-string-key";
    public static final String DAILY_FORECAST = "DAILY_FORECAST";
    public static final String HOURLY_FORECAST = "HOURLY_FORECAST";
    public static final String BG_GRADIENT = "BG_GRADIENT";

    private Forecast mForecast;
    private ColorWheel mColorWheel;
    private int[] mBackground;

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;
    protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;

    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;// = -116.2296;

    @BindView(R.id.layoutBackground)
    RelativeLayout mLayoutBackground;
    @BindView(R.id.timeLabel)
    TextView mTimeLabel;
    @BindView(R.id.temperatureLabel)
    TextView mTemperatureLabel;
    @BindView(R.id.humidityValue)
    TextView mHumidityValue;
    @BindView(R.id.precipValue)
    TextView mPrecipValue;
    @BindView(R.id.summaryLabel)
    TextView mSummaryLabel;
    @BindView(R.id.iconImageView)
    ImageView mIconImageView;
    @BindView(R.id.refreshImageView)
    ImageView mRefreshImageView;
    @BindView(R.id.progressBar)
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    @BindView(R.id.locationLabel)
    TextView mLocationLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        mLastUpdateTime = "";

        updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mColorWheel = new ColorWheel();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Updating values from bundle");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Update the value of mRequestingLocationUpdates from the Bundle, and make sure that
            // the Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons are correctly enabled or disabled.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY)) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                        REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY);
            }

            // Update the value of mCurrentLocation from the Bundle and update the UI to show the
            // correct latitude and longitude.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_KEY)) {
                // Since LOCATION_KEY was found in the Bundle, we can be sure that mCurrentLocation
                // is not null.
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LOCATION_KEY);
            }

            // Update the value of mLastUpdateTime from the Bundle and update the UI.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY)) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY);
            }
            updateDisplay();
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    private void setBackgroundGradient() {
        mBackground = mColorWheel.getColors();

        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[]{mBackground[0], mBackground[1]});
        gd.setCornerRadius(0f);

        mLayoutBackground.setBackground(gd);
    }

    private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
        String apiKey = "50e826df5889d0d215cdcbae50d182e3";
        String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
                "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            toggleRefresh();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            mForecast = parseForecastDetails(jsonData);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateDisplay();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            alertUserAboutError();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, forecastUrl);
    }

    private void toggleRefresh() {
        if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private Forecast parseForecastDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        Forecast forecast = new Forecast();

        forecast.setCurrentForecast(getCurrentDetails(jsonData));
        forecast.setHourlyForecast(getHourlyForecast(jsonData));
        forecast.setDailyForecast(getDailyForecast(jsonData));

        return forecast;
    }

    private Day[] getDailyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        JSONObject daily = forecast.getJSONObject("daily");
        JSONArray data = daily.getJSONArray("data");

        Day[] days = new Day[data.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonHour = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Day day = new Day();
            day.setTime(jsonHour.getLong("time"));
            day.setSummary(jsonHour.getString("summary"));
            day.setTemperatureMax(jsonHour.getInt("temperatureMax"));
            day.setTimezone(timezone);
            day.setIcon(jsonHour.getString("icon"));

            days[i] = day;
        }

        return days;
    }

    private Hour[] getHourlyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        JSONObject hourly = forecast.getJSONObject("hourly");
        JSONArray data = hourly.getJSONArray("data");

        Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonHour = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Hour hour = new Hour();
            hour.setTime(jsonHour.getLong("time"));
            hour.setSummary(jsonHour.getString("summary"));
            hour.setTemperature(jsonHour.getInt("temperature"));
            hour.setTimezone(timezone);
            hour.setIcon(jsonHour.getString("icon"));

            hours[i] = hour;
        }

        return hours;
    }

    private Current getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");

        JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");

        Current current = new Current(
                currently.getString("icon"),
                currently.getLong("time"),
                currently.getDouble("temperature"),
                currently.getDouble("humidity"),
                currently.getDouble("precipProbability"),
                currently.getString("summary"),
                forecast.getString("timezone")
        );
        Log.i(TAG, current.toString());
        return current;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.refreshImageView)
    public void refreshPage(View view) {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        setBackgroundGradient();

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.dailyButton)
    public void startDailyActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DailyForecastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DAILY_FORECAST, mForecast.getDailyForecast());
        if (mBackground != null) {
            intent.putExtra(BG_GRADIENT, mBackground);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.hourButton)
    public void startHourlyActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HourlyForecastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(HOURLY_FORECAST, mForecast.getHourlyForecast());
        if (mBackground != null) {
            intent.putExtra(BG_GRADIENT, mBackground);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    public void startUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    public void stopUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, MainActivity.this);
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        Current current = mForecast.getCurrentForecast();
        mTemperatureLabel.setText(current.getTemperature() + "");
        mTimeLabel.setText("The time is " + current.getFormattedTime());
        mHumidityValue.setText(current.getHumidity() + "");
        mPrecipValue.setText(current.getPrecipChance() + "%");
        mSummaryLabel.setText(current.getSummary());
        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), current.getIconId(), null);
        mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
        // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
        // location updates if the user has requested them.

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");

        // If the initial location was never previously requested, we use
        // FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() to get it. If it was previously requested, we store
        // its value in the Bundle and check for it in onCreate(). We
        // do not request it again unless the user specifically requests location updates by pressing
        // the Start Updates button.
        //
        // Because we cache the value of the initial location in the Bundle, it means that if the
        // user launches the activity,
        // moves to a new location, and then changes the device orientation, the original location
        // is displayed as the activity is re-created.
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        }

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "location changed");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        getForecast(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY, mRequestingLocationUpdates);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(LOCATION_KEY, mCurrentLocation);
        savedInstanceState.putString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY, mLastUpdateTime);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant tell from looking at the code because i find runtime permissions too difficult to understand, but if you start with onlocationchanged() and ask yourself "what is required for this to be called" and trace back from there... putting several logs in your code to make sure the expected behaviors are happening, i bet you'll find the problem.

Comment: onLocationChanged() is implemented from the LocationListener interface. I can't figure out what triggers it.

Comment: Well... not the exact trigger, but several things are required in order for it to work, for example startlocationupdates () has to run successfully but you dont have any logs to verify that.

Comment: Thanks for talking about the runtime permissions. I never asked for permission and I was targeting sdk 24. That was what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi your api is working fine, i have checked. You have issue with your current latitude and longitude. So, i have one solution for you.

Please check how i'm using in my app and its working perfect.I'm using **fused api** for update location please follow few steps.

**Step 1. Make this class 
GoogleLocationService.java**

```
public class GoogleLocationService {
private GoogleServicesCallbacks callbacks = new GoogleServicesCallbacks();
LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener;
Context activity;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30000;


public GoogleLocationService(Context activity, LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener) {
    this.locationUpdateListener = locationUpdateListener;
    this.activity = activity;
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    //Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(callbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(callbacks)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

}

private class GoogleServicesCallbacks implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (connectionResult.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Google play service not updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location.hasAccuracy()) {
            if (location.getAccuracy() < 30) {
                locationUpdateListener.updateLocation(location);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean locationEnabled(Context context) {
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gps_enabled;
}

private boolean servicesConnected(Context context) {
    return isPackageInstalled(GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_PACKAGE, context);
}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}


public void startUpdates() {
    /*
     * Connect the client. Don't re-start any requests here; instead, wait
     * for onResume()
     */
    if (servicesConnected(activity)) {
        if (locationEnabled(activity)) {
            locationUpdateListener.canReceiveLocationUpdates();
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to get your location.Please turn on your device Gps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Google play service not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//stop location updates
public void stopUpdates() {
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

//start location updates
private void startLocationUpdates() {

    if (checkSelfPermission(activity, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(activity, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, callbacks);
    }
}

public void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, callbacks);
    }
}

public void startGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void closeGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

 }
```

**Step2. Make this interface 
LocationUpdateListener.java**

```
 public interface LocationUpdateListener {

/**
 * Called immediately the service starts if the service can obtain location
 */
void canReceiveLocationUpdates();

/**
 * Called immediately the service tries to start if it cannot obtain location - eg the user has disabled wireless and
 */
void cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();

/**
 * Called whenever the location has changed (at least non-trivially)
 * @param location
 */
void updateLocation(Location location);

/**
 * Called when GoogleLocationServices detects that the device has moved to a new location.
 * @param localityName The name of the locality (somewhere below street but above area).
 */
void updateLocationName(String localityName, Location location);
}
```

Step 3. Call this in your class oncreate or where you want to get location

private GoogleLocationService googleLocationService;

```
 googleLocationService = new GoogleLocationService(context, new LocationUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void canReceiveLocationUpdates() {
    }

    @Override
    public void cannotReceiveLocationUpdates() {
    }

    //update location to our servers for tracking purpose
    @Override
    public void updateLocation(Location location) {
        if (location != null ) {
            Timber.e("updated location %1$s %2$s", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateLocationName(String localityName, Location location) {

        googleLocationService.stopLocationUpdates();
    }
});
googleLocationService.startUpdates();


and call this onDestroy 
if (googleLocationService != null) {
    googleLocationService.stopLocationUpdates();
}
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I put a log in the override **updateLocation()** method and it didn't run? However I put another log in the method **canReceiveLocationUpdates()**, and it ran just fine.

Comment: did you try my way ? i'm using same code and its working fine

Comment: Thank you. Your way worked, but I wasn't asking for permission. Thank you for these classes though. They work great.

Comment: Great ! There is no need any special permission.Just location permission needed. If your problem solved then can you accept the answer.